# Halal marriage relationship in islam

Tags: nikah

Assalam valikum, 
My parents are looking to make my marriage with my mother's sister's son's daughter. I have a doubt to marry her as per relation she is my daughter.
Is this relationship accepted in islam ..?
One can marry mother's sister's son's daughter ..?
(Mothers sister's husband is from another blood)
Please let me know 
Jazakallah..!!!